# How to get container configuration programmatically with containerd runtime?

Tags: go, containerd

I use [containerd interface for logging plugins](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/pull/3085). Also I'm looking for a way to get the **container config** that **kubelet** passes to **containerd** to run containers. I am interested in the ability to find out the path to the container log file, as well as the ability to receive a signal that the file needs to be reopened after log rotation. I tried looking at https://github.com/containerd/containerd and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/README.md, but didn't find anything useful.
Is there a way to get the functionality I need and then write code like this?

```
config, _ := runtime.GetCurrentContainerConfig()
logFilePath := config.logFilePath
if runtime.ReopenLogFileRequest {
   file.Open(logFilePath)
}
```